# Displaying large png file using zoom from thumb view image

Tags: android, performance

Hi I have successfully coded my app to display large png files from thumb view. When the thumb view is clicked the image enlarges to full screen. The problem I'm having is the app runs very slow due to a lack of memory. So I have made an attempt to save memory by using "notifyDrawable" however I am a noobie at this and I have probably gone about this the wrong way. I was wondering if anyone could suggest of a better way to save memory and a way to make my app run more smoothly. Here is the code I've used:

```
final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.page1);
        }
        @Override
        public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

            final Drawable previousDrawable = getDrawable();
            super.zoomImageFromThumb(drawable);
            notifyDrawable(drawable, true);
            notifyDrawable(previousDrawable, false);
        }

        private static void notifyDrawable(Drawable drawable, final boolean isDisplayed) {
            if (drawable instanceof English_Infants) {
                // The drawable is a CountingBitmapDrawable, so notify it
                ((English_Infants) drawable).setIsDisplayed(isDisplayed);
            } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
                // The drawable is a LayerDrawable, so recurse on each layer
                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
                for (int i = 0, z = layerDrawable.getNumberOfLayers(); i < z; i++) {
                    notifyDrawable(layerDrawable.getDrawable(i), isDisplayed);
                }
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: I suggest Universal Image Loader . it buffer your images and increase the performance.

Comment: @Rudi I've looked into it there but I've no idea how to incorporate into my code.

Comment: you can use it's tutorial in the web page. also there is a example there and not that complicated.